# Show different forms using buttons with animation

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms, transition

I have two buttons "form1" and "form2" which are stacked one above the other.

When I click on form1 button, a form with id="fone" should be shown in such a way that the stacked buttons are faded out and the form is faded in.The form has "back" button,on which when it is clicked,the form fades out and the stacked buttons are faded in.

Same happens when I click on form2 button,another form with form id="ftwo" is faded in and so on.
** HTML **

```
<div id="buttons">
<button id="one" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Form1</button>
<button id="two" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">from2</button>
</div>

<br>
<div id="fone" class="col-sm-2">
<form role="form" class="hide">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Input me" >
     <input type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-danger" >
    <button class="btn btn-primary"> BACK TO BUTTON LIST </button>
</form>
</div>

    <div id="ftwo" class="col-sm-2">
<form role="form" class="hide">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Input me" >
     <input type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-danger" >
    <button class="btn btn-primary"> BACK TO BUTTON LIST </button>
</form>
</div>
```

Sorry for this kind of a question.Im new to jquery.I could make a fiddle for this http://jsfiddle.net/2HwHf/1/

But I have no idea how this can eb made possible using it.When i googled I found that adding css classes onclick will do the job.But I would like to have some nice transitions happening in between,like the button collapses apart and the form is faded in,or something of that sort?

Please give me some help.I have worked with css ,but havnt touched jquery yet,would liek to know how this can be made possible using jquery.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a full example for you
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2HwHf/8/)

```
// Form Open Action
$('button').on('click', function(){
var whatForm = $(this).attr('id');
$('#buttons').slideUp();
$('.'+whatForm).slideDown();
});

// Back Button Action
$('.backbtn').on('click', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$('#buttons').slideDown();
$('form').slideUp();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of options in jQuery to do that. Here is a simple approach:

```
$('#two').click(function () {
  $('#buttons').hide();
  $('#ftwo').fadeIn();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2HwHf/7/

Comment: Ya but here the buttons are not faded out and in that place the form should be faded in

Comment: The two buttons need to fadeOut or just the clicked button?

Comment: The two buttons should be faded out and in that place the form should appear.But instead of fade is there any transition effects?

Comment: Updated: http://jsfiddle.net/2HwHf/7/. You can just hide div, like in the example. For more complex animations, see jquery UI: https://jqueryui.com/

Answer (score 0):

To build off of marcelo, you would want to add a fadeOut to the button.  [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2HwHf/5/)

```
$('#one').click(function(){
    $('#one').fadeOut( "slow", function() {
        $('#fone').fadeToggle();
  });

});
```